# How to work exponential function backwards from result?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

There is a question that is asking me T=Temperature(Celsius) (t=minutes since poured in) where the function for finding temperature of coffee is $$ T=90(3^{-0.05t})$$ (initial coffee temp is 90) it wants me to find the amount of time (t) until the temperature has halved. How do i work backwards to get the time till initial temperature is half.

I just want to know any function or how to use this function to get the time until the initial temperature is halved already knowing the beginning value result of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you're solving is
$$
90\times 3^{-0.05t} = 45
$$
You can start by dividing both sides by $90$:
$$
3^{-0.05t} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
Now take the natural logarithm on both sides:
$$
\ln{(3^{-0.05t})} = -0.05t \ln{3} = \ln{(\frac{1}{2})} = -\ln{2}
$$
Divide both sides by $-0.05 \ln{3}$ to get
$$
t = \frac{\ln{2}}{0.05 \ln{3}} \approx 12.62
$$
Easy as can be!

Comment: you are a lifesaver thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. In the future, will you be able to solve similar problems?

Comment: actually i tried doing and i am a bit confused about the last 2 bits

Comment: i know that you are putting both sides in the natural logarithm but how did you get those results i didn't get the same when i put it into my calculator. and then why and how would i divide both sides by −0.05ln3 and after i do how come that is the answer. and the google calculator isnt doing correctly and i am very confused.

Comment: okay so when you are dividing -ln2 by -0.05ln3 how come you get     ln2/0.05ln3

Comment: $$
\frac{-\ln{2}}{-0.05 \ln{3}} = \frac{(-1) \cdot \ln{2}}{(-1) \cdot 0.05 \ln{3}} = \frac{\ln{2}}{0.05 \ln{3}} 
$$

Comment: okay so how do i do this one that already has a log in it?

Comment: 155=40log10(500t+1)

Comment: Just use the rules of algebra and logarithms. Please try it and write where you end up.