# If $10000 = 5000(1.1^t)$, then what is $t$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, exponentiation

$V = $ Value of computer, $t = $ years. 
A computer appreciates in value by 10% a year. If the computer costs 5000 when new find the value of $t$ when $V$ is 10000:

Rule for working out $V$: $$V = 5000(1.1^t)$$
So

> $$10000 = 5000(1.1^t)$$
>   What is $t$?

Comment: What about using logarithms ?

Comment: yes but how can i user logarithms to solve this problem please?

Comment: Hi again eagel! Remember the other question that I answered? (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3311171/how-to-work-exponential-function-backwards-from-result/3311172#3311172) It was very similar to this. You can use the methods to answer this one too. Did you learn something from the other question?

Comment: yes i did thank you i just thought that it couldn't be applied to this problem because i tried and forgot the natural logarithms, thank you thought will do it.

Comment: Of course it can be applied to this problem. The equation is just different, but in both cases you just have to move the terms around a bit and take the logarithm on both sides. Just revise the definition of logarithms and you should be fine. Report back when you have tried and show what you got.

Comment: When you get to this step: $t = \log_{1.1} 2$, you can use the change of base formula to get $t = \frac{\log 2}{\log 1.1}$ where the logarithm can be in any base.

Answer (score 1):

I have: $1.1^t=\frac{10000}{5000}=2$. I obtain, in conclusion: $t=\log_{1.1}{2}$, about $7.27$.